# Using a std::list with gSOAP

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, wsdl, gsoap

I'm trying to use gSOAP with C++ to pass a std::list of a simple structure using the soapstd2 compiler to generate the relevant WSDL for a legacy application that I'm trying to offer as a web service.

Heres the gSOAP header that I have defined in the legacy C++ app:

```
//gsoap ns service name:        Arpa service described at http://localhost:5801/ArpaService
//gsoap ns service protocol:    SOAP
//gsoap ns service namespace:   http://localhost:5801/arpa.wsdl
//gsoap ns service location:    http://localhost:5801/arpaserver.cgi

#import "stl.h"

class ns__arpaTarget
{
public:
    int    nTgtNo;
    std::string  name;
    double dRange;
    double dBearing;
    ns__arpaTarget();
    ~ns__arpaTarget();
};

class ns__arpaList
{
public:
    std::list <ns__arpaTarget> arpa_lst;   
};

//gsoap ns service method: 
int ns__getArpaList( ns__arpaList* lst );
```

I'm compiling this within Visual Studio 2008, with the following pre build event to generate the WSDL:

```
W:\gSOAP\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\bin\win32\soapcpp2  -I W:\gSOAP\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import -t W:\gSOAP\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\WS\typemap.dat -j -s gSOAPArpaWebService.h
```

This is all building fine at the server end (I have an implementation of the function which builds and runs and supplies a list of my simple structure) - it's also generating the WSDL which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="Arpa"
  targetNamespace="http://localhost:5801/arpa.wsdl"
  xmlns:tns="http://localhost:5801/arpa.wsdl"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ns="http://localhost:5801/arpa.wsdl"
  xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:HTTP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
  xmlns:MIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
  xmlns:DIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/dime/wsdl/"
  xmlns:WSDL="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<types>

  <schema targetNamespace="http://localhost:5801/arpa.wsdl"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns="http://localhost:5801/arpa.wsdl"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    <complexType name="arpaTarget"><!-- ns__arpaTarget -->
          <sequence>
            <element name="nTgtNo" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__arpaTarget::nTgtNo -->
            <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__arpaTarget::name -->
            <element name="dRange" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__arpaTarget::dRange -->
            <element name="dBearing" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><!-- ns__arpaTarget::dBearing -->
          </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <!-- operation request element -->
    <element name="getArpaList">
      <complexType>
          <sequence>
          </sequence>
      </complexType>
    </element>
    <!-- operation response element -->
    <element name="arpaList">
      <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element name="arpa-lst" type="ns:arpaTarget" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/><!-- ns__arpaList::arpa_lst -->
          </sequence>
      </complexType>
    </element>
  </schema>

</types>

<message name="getArpaList">
  <part name="Body" element="ns:getArpaList"/><!-- ns__getArpaList::ns__getArpaList -->
</message>

<message name="arpaList">
  <part name="Body" element="ns:arpaList"/><!-- ns__getArpaList::lst -->
</message>

<portType name="ArpaPortType">
  <operation name="getArpaList">
    <documentation>Service definition of function ns__getArpaList</documentation>
    <input message="tns:getArpaList"/>
    <output message="tns:arpaList"/>
  </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="Arpa" type="tns:ArpaPortType">
  <SOAP:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="getArpaList">
    <SOAP:operation soapAction=""/>
    <input>
          <SOAP:body parts="Body" use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
          <SOAP:body parts="Body" use="literal"/>
    </output>
  </operation>
</binding>

<service name="Arpa">
  <documentation>service described at http://localhost:5801/ArpaService</documentation>
  <port name="Arpa" binding="tns:Arpa">
    <SOAP:address location="http://localhost:5801/arpaserver.cgi"/>
  </port>
</service>

</definitions>
```

At the client end I'm referencing the generated gSOAP WSDL and successfully importing the service via an ASP.NET web application - but when I try to use the service function of the imported service to retrieve the list of ns__arpaTarget types the service only offers the following function signiture that I don't understand or know how to use (perhaps this is my problem?):

```
Radar_Services_Web_Client.ArpaSrv.arpaTarget[] ArpaPortTypeClient.getArpaList( Radar_Services_Web_Client.ArpaSrv.getArpaList getArpaList1 )
```

Note: I have tried this without a list and I am able to get a single structure out from the service into the client call successfully. I've also tried a list of pointers to ns__arpaTarget - as the gSOAP documentation tells me this is a safer way of doing so but the same problem occurs (i.e I get the same strange signiture to use in the client).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks, Gary.

Comment: Not knowing exactly what you're trying to do, a `std::list` is a C++ thing.  It isn't understood by anything but a C++ compiler, and even that has its limitations.  Unless what you're doing knows how to properly serialize/marshal the list's data, I don't see how this will work.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie The gSOAP help states: (Section 11.11.8 STL Containers)
gSOAP supports the STL containers std::deque, std::list, std::set, and std::vector.
STL containers can only be used within classes to declare members that contain multiple values.

Comment: Apologies Paul - I missed the at on the above comment @PaulMcKenzie